# System of homogen linear equations in a division ring

Tags: linear-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a division ring (one does not suppose that $K$ is commutative) and $m,n$ two positive integers such that $m<n$. Consider the system of homogen linear equations
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\cdots+a_{1n}x_n&=&0\\
a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\cdots+a_{2n}x_n&=&0\\
\vdots\qquad\qquad\qquad&\vdots&\vdots\\
a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2+\cdots+a_{mn}x_n&=&0\\
\end{array}\right.$$
where the $a_{ij}$'s are in $K$. Can we assert that this system admits an infinity of solutions. Obviously, it is true when $K$ is commutative. But when $K$ is not, I do not know if this results still holds.

Is it also true in the non commutative case?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system has infinitely many solutions, even when $K$ is non-commutative.  The reason is that row reduction is still possible over a non-commutative division ring.

---

Side remark: if $K$ is commutative, the system has infinitely many solutions only if $K$ is infinite.  If $K$ is not commutative, then it is automatically infinite by [Wedderburn's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem).